# svnadmin dump of a folder not getting some of the subfolders

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I am trying to dump a folder and its sub folder contents from the current SVN repository using svnadmin dump. However, it does not dump all the subfolders under it. I am not sure if this is an indication of some sort of svn corruption or if I am not using the right command.

Here is the command that I am using

```
svnadmin dump d:/svnrepo --incremental | svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs include MyFolder > MyFolder.dmp
```

How do I ensure that all subfolders are part of the dump. And, if this is an indication of svn corruption how do I fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that all subfolders are part of the dump.

Read [command documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html).

> --incremental option, which simply causes that first revision in the dump stream to **contain only the files and directories modified in that revision**, instead of being presented as the addition of a new tree, and in exactly **the same way that every other revision in the dump** file is presented.

Comment: Removed the --incremental option. It did not make any difference. Still have the same issue. Any other ideas/ suggestions?

Comment: 1. prepare *full dump* 2. Read dump